# ¿Se puede configurar el Android SDK que instala Visual Studio para que sea reconocido por el comand flutter doctor?

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter

Me encuentro en la instalación de flutter y anteriormente he utilizado Android Studio para esto, por lo general al utilizar el comando `flutter doctor` este muestra que se necesita ciertos requerimientos, uno de esos requerimientos es `Android toolchain - develop for Android devices`, por lo general esto es sencillo cuando se instala directamente Android Studio ya que viene con todos los paquetes necesarios para el desarrollo, pero  quisiera hacer uso de otras herramientas y no tener que depender 100% de Android Studio, sé que podemos desarrollar con otros IDE's como puede ser los de JetBrains o incluso con editores de texto como VS CODE pero no quiero verme obligado a instalar un IDE como android studio para tener el SDK y utilizarlo en otro entorno de desarrollo. Cuando instalé los paquetes en Visual Studio me di cuenta que este incluye dicho SDK pero el comando `sdkmanager` no lo reconoce en las terminales ¿hay alguna manera de saber el path del Android SDK que instala Visual studio y es posible configurarlo para flutter?